# C++11 std::this_thread - How to cancel sleep_until ()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, std, sleep

**Is there any way to "cancel" the:**

```
std::this_thread::sleep_until(now + std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
```

Let's imagine the following scenario:

I set my thread to wake up in 200ms... but after 10ms, I receive a new request that my thread must wake up in 100ms...

So the thread should wake up in:
100ms and then at 200ms (after the current time, of course).

Thanks :)

Comment: wouldn't this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025015/how-do-i-wake-up-a-sleeping-pthread

Comment: That question with corresponding answers are related to the pthread library. And this question is about the C++ standard threads.

Comment: You can't but have a look at [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) which allows you to notify threads depending on a certain condition.

Comment: This answer shows how to do it with `std::conditional_variable` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775153/stopping-long-sleep-threads

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with `sleep_until`. Have a look at condition variables ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/ ). Should be usable for exactly what you want.